# missing javadoc detail in intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

Just switch the IDE from  Eclipse to intelliJ, when I use ctrl+q to try to pop up more explainations for the method, it shows no details like this. How can I fix it to get same information as Eclipse does?

[image]

Comment: Just use `ctrl + b` or `ctrl + alt + b` on method for which you want implementation and `javadoc`. If `javadoc` is available then it will show you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because you didn't set Java source path in the project structure dialog.

Go to `File > Project Structure` and select `SDKs` from the left side. Then select your project JDK level (In your case it should be 1.8) and add JDK source path in `Sourcepath` tab.

Usually it should be named as src.zip and placed inside your JDK folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Trying to follow @Chathura Buddhika's answer I found I didn't have the jdk source installed:

```
$ file /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/src.zip
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/src.zip: broken symbolic link to ../openjdk-8/src.zip
```

I **installed the source package**, restarted intellij, and then documentation "just worked". The Sourcepath got automatically added to the Project structure.

Debian/Ubuntu with open jdk8:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-source
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64340730/8954109

Answer (score 1):

Other thing you might consider if you are on a Maven project, is to download the sources in Maven menu on the upper right (see pic. bellow)

[image]

Comment: Awesome, this worked. wonder how to set this to global default option

Comment: You don't need to set it to global, I think IntelliJ does it by default for every maven project

Answer (score 0):

You can simply navigate to the class `PrintStream` where you can find the complete documentation by -

- Right click on the method
- Go to
- Implementation
- Select the class where you want to see its implementation
- In this case `PrintStream`

(Shortcuts could vary as defined by users)