# openjdk-8-jdk - missing src.zip?

Tags: java, java-8

Below is the required info -

```
apt list  | grep installed | grep -i openjdk-8-jdk

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

openjdk-8-jdk-headless/focal-security,focal-security,now 8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~20.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openjdk-8-jdk/focal-security,focal-security,now 8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~20.04 amd64 [installed]
```

To query the installed binaries, i tried below -

```
$ dpkg -L openjdk-8-jdk
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/jvm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/appletviewer
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jconsole
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/jawt.h
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux/jawt_md.h
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/jconsole.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/appletviewer.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/jconsole.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/appletviewer.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jconsole.1.gz
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/test-amd64
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/test-amd64/check-hotspot-hotspot.log.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/test-amd64/check-jdk-hotspot.log.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/test-amd64/check-langtools-hotspot.log.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/test-amd64/failed_tests-hotspot.tar.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/test-amd64/jtreg-summary-hotspot.log.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/test-amd64/jtreport-hotspot.tar.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jdk
```

**On looking in to the `jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64` directory, I see the link for `src.zip` is broken**

```
$ ll
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Sep  6 20:44 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep  6 20:43 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 Aug  3 06:46 ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION -> jre/ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  6 20:44 bin/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   41 Aug  3 06:46 docs -> ../../../share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep  6 20:44 include/
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Sep  6 20:43 jre/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep  6 20:44 lib/
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Sep  6 20:43 man/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Aug  3 06:46 src.zip -> ../openjdk-8/src.zip  //this is in red i.e. broken
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 Aug  3 06:46 THIRD_PARTY_README -> jre/THIRD_PARTY_README
```

Now how do i get the sources, i think i can get them manually - is this the only option I am left with??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

assuming you are running Ubuntu (it's the same for Debian), sources for `openjdk-8` are in the package [`openjdk-8-source`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/openjdk-8-source).

if you look at the [filelist](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/openjdk-8-source/filelist) of the package, you will find:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-8/src.zip
```

the package can be installed in the usual way:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-source
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are in centos, then use

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-src
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.